# Should I have numerous Login keyrings?

Tags: keyrings

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. While exploring options for eliminating requests for keyring password (found in numerous other postings--not my question here), I opened Passwords and Keys and discovered 21 pages of Passwords (keyrings?) named "Login" and none with any other name (e.g. Default).

Is this normal?
Is it a problem?
Should I leave them?
Should I delete them?
All of them?

Comment: Before deleting anything always make sure you have a valid, working backup.  I don't know how many times I see folks with data loss issues, and they don't have their own verified backup.

Comment: I have no idea how to back up the Passwords (keyrings?).

Comment: BTW, there are 390 (if I counted accurately--near that if I didn't) entries all named "Login" and no others.