# login keyring keeps popping up

Tags: login, password, keyrings

I'm having an issue with the login keyring since yesterday. It suddenly won't unlock, it keeps popping up straight after i type the password and it keeps going on and on unless i reduce it to an icon or until I type 21 times the password (just realized that while typing my question) it won't stop.

looking at the "password and keys" i found that there are 21 login folders  [image: Password menu, Login folders]

Why is it doing that? 
By logic i would delete all the login folders and leave only one, is that fine or it will bring any issue later?

Thanks anyone for helping with that.

ps.I have been searching on Google and looking on other questions asked here and I only found a similar question without answer: [Should I have numerous Login keyrings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/857413/should-i-have-numerous-login-keyrings)